# Setting elixir not to merge css files

Tags: laravel, gulp, laravel-5, laravel-elixir

Is there a way to prevent elixir from merging my assets? My code:

```
mix.sass(['comingsoon/*.scss', 'comingsoon/**/*.scss'], 'public/assets/comingsoon/css')
        .scripts(['comingsoon/*.js', 'comingsoon/**/*.js'], 'public/assets/comingsoon/js');
```

I set this to compile all of my sass and js files, but I want to keep the files separate just the way I separate my pre-compiled files. For example, I have home.scss and contact.scss, I want them to be compiled into home.css and contact.css instead of them being merged to app.css.

Ho do I do that?

Comment: Multiple `mix.sass` calls. Combining them means fewer HTTP requests, though, and is generally considered a best practice.

Comment: So what you basically say here is that If I don't want the files to be merged I can't set gulp to automatically watch all my scss files?